# How to get width of a sub component onResize in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, resize

- I'm trying to get the width of a sub component when resizing window.
- I know how to get the width of the whole app by doing:

  ```
    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event']) 
     onResize(event) {
      event.target.innerWidth;
      console.log('Window resize: ' + event.target.innerWidth);
   }
  ```

But I'm not really sure how to **ONLY** target a sub-component and get its width when resizing window.

```
<div class = 'panel-2'></div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, please? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
 <div class = "main">
     <div class = 'left-section'>Left bar</div>
         <div class = 'right-section'>
             <div class = 'panel-1'></div>
             <div class = 'panel-2'></div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#panel2` to your panel 2 and then in your TS file add `@ViewChild('panel2') panel2;` as a property of the class.

When the `ngOnInit` hook is triggered you can then access `this.panel2.nativeElement`, which you can also use inside of your HostListener, so you do not need to rely on the event's target anymore!